# How can I download a website with embedded MP4 videos using HTTrack?

Tags: httrack

I’m trying to download a website that has videos embedded for tutorials.

I’ve successfully captured the login and downloaded the website unfortunately the embedded MP4 video is not captured for playback off-line.

Another issue is below each embedded video there is a download link to the
MP4. How do I set up HTTrack Website Copier to download the embedded video to be viewed in embedded form for off-line use and not to follow the download button URL? The embedded video and download button share the same URL.

If you can recommend an alternative program to HTTrack that might perform my request feel free to post.